# GlideApp cannot be found

Tags: java, android, android-glide

> error: cannot find symbol variable GlideApp

This is the error I have been getting.
I'm using Android studio 3.3.1 and imported these modules for glide.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

---

```
GlideApp.with(this /* context */)
            .load(storageReference)
            .into(MainImage);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use generated API in Glide you need to create a class and extend `AppGlideModule` and use `@GlideModule` annotation, for example:

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

}
```

After this rebuild and you should be able to use `GlideApp` for more information visit:
http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html

Answer (score 4):

If **GlideAPP** can't be generated

```
annotationProcessor com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0
```

Must be with ‘AppGlideModule Implementation class’ In the same module

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
def glide_version = "4.12.0"

implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"

kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
```

Then *Sync* it will work.

[Working Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCmvf.png)

Optional: You can also do this. `Build -> Make Module`

Comment: thanks, your optional solution helped me when i use the glide library in an android library

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kotlin, try to use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor`.

```
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please manually check your code for errors. Errors in code will cause auto-generated class "GlideApp" to disappear when you try to build.

Android Studio will first check for imports and find that GlideApp does not exist. But it will not show you up in-code (after import) errors unless you open each class one by one.